# Calling MVC controller method from a different application

Tags: json, authentication, xmlhttprequest, aurelia

I've deployed my MVC5 app to IIS and one of the methods on my controllers returns a json object. The app works fine when I browse to the site. I can see the json object in my browser if I call the method on the controller directly.

But now I am building an Aurelia app and doing a fetch on the api method. In Chome, with developer tools, under Console, I get an the following error:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:55829' is therefore not allowed access.

Anything I need to do to my hosting application's web.config?

This is how I am calling the method from Aurelia:

```
http.fetch('http://localhost/MyCart/Home/GetProducts')
    .then(result => result.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data.description);
});
```

Comment: Is the Aurelia app hosted separately? If it is on its own port then you'll need to enable CORS to communicate between the two. It depends what library you're using to supply `http` but it likely has some "CORS" mode you can turn on, and the server will need CORS setup as well.

Comment: Got it to work by enabling CORS on my hosting app's web.config. Aurelia app is in development mode so it is not hosted yet, only though Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by enabling CORS on my hosted app's web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```